# OpenGL: Textures seem not to blend correctly on top of translucent surface

Tags: android, opengl-es, alphablending

I am drawing objects in OpenGL in this order and z-order:

- A background quad,
- background objects = images with titles (textures)
- a translucent black quad which darkens the background objects (colored quad with low alpha value),
- and foreground objects = images with titles (textures, but the one in the center has a white quad behind it)

Currently, it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

This is not as it's supposed to be - the 5 objects around "Chikinki" (Timid Tiger, The Bishops,...) should be as bright as the "Chikinki" picture. Also, all titles (including Chikinki's) are darker than the textures really are. It seems to me as though the white quad behind the "Chikinki" image somehow forces OpenGL to draw the pic in front of it rightly. Without the translucent black quad (which is there to darken all objects except the one in the middle and 5 around it), everything is fine. So I suspect that this translucent quad somehow bleeds through, although the other objects are drawn after it and have a higher z-value.

As mentioned, the objects are drawn back-to-front, and also laid out back-to-front z-wise. Blending is always enabled. The white rectangle has blending function: `gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` and all images have function `gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`. Depth-test is enabled.

Relevant texture-fill quad drawing code (too dim in the screenshot):

```
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureName);
gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mFVertexBuffer);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTexBuffer);

gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

mFVertexBuffer.position(0);
mTexBuffer.position(0);
mIndexBuffer.position(0);

gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

Relevant color-fill quad drawing code (shown OK in the screenshot):

```
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mFVertexBuffer);

gl.glColor4f(mRed, mGreen, mBlue, mAlpha);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
mFVertexBuffer.position(0);
mIndexBuffer.position(0);

gl.glPopMatrix();
gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
```

Have you got any clue what could be causing the darkening of these objects which should by all means be fully opaque, considering that they are drawn AFTER the translucent quad and have a HIGHER z-value?

**SOLUTION**

Tim pointed out in the comments that texture drawing is affected by the current color buffer (its alpha value). Calling `gl.glColor4f(1,1,1,1);` before drawing the images did the trick, reverting the earlier call to `gl.glColor4f()` with a lower-than-1 alpha value.

Comment: If you're really drawing those tiles last, and they are fully opaque (alpha == 1), then it should be working as you describe. Care to show your OpenGL drawing code? I suspect you have a conceptual error somewhere.

Comment: As you can guess, the code base is quite huge now, I wrote my own mesh classes and drawing abstractions - so, difficult to paste :( I am sure that they are drawn last, fully opaque. The white rectangle you see in the center (which is drawn OK!) only differs from the rest in that it is color-filled instead of texture-filled. I could paste the color-fill and texture-fill code if you wish?

Comment: You can add whatever you want to your post, but the more relevant information you're able to post increases the chances that someone can see what the problem is.

Comment: I thought you had a suspicion what the problem might be. I added those methods.

Comment: Do you ever set glColor4f before drawing your textured quads? Even if you're using textures, the color is still modulated by the active color. So if your last call to glColor4f was anything other than (1,1,1,1) it will be multiplied with the texture color.

Comment: That did it - thank you very much! You made someone happy :)